# VBA Excel: not statement & formula

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way of combining a `not` statement with a function in the following way:

I want it to work like this example

```
MsgBox not False
```

which returns `True`.

But if I add a function instead of the boolean statement

```
MsgBox not myFunction()
```

then it returns a `mismatch error`.

`myFunction()` is supposed to return `True` or `False`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried `MsgBox Not (myFunction())`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to give us more code, as the following works:

```
Public Sub test()
    MsgBox Not myfunction()
End Sub

Function myfunction() As Boolean
    myfunction = False
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply

```
MsgBox Not Application.Evaluate(myFunction)
```

Comment: Why would you Evaluate rather than just calling the function?

Comment: Because calling the function gave a missmatch error. Evaluate worked as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

what is myFunction defined as? if its not :

```
Function myFunction(...) As Boolean
'...
End Function
```

that would be why, 'not' operator is reserved for Boolean (true/false)

if your function is like this and only recieves 1 and 0:

```
Function myFunction(...) As Integer
```

add this to the call :

```
MsgBox not CBool(myFunction(...))
```

or if you are actually trying to compare text:

```
Function myFunction(...) As String
```

then you will need:

EDIT: not string.compare, (StrComp(Str1, Str2, vbTextCompare) = 0)

hope that helps :)

Comment: `String.Compare` is VB.NET, not VBA.